# how can i display add to cart button in listview with baseadapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

i am working on a ecommerce app and i have a list where list of items will be there. Just like product name, price, discounted value etc fetched from database.

i am using ListView to show products where every item have there seprate **Menu_ID**. Whenever i click on list item following code is run where i use **putExtra** to open speciefic **menu_id** item details.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // go to menu detail page
            Intent iDetail = new Intent(ActivityMenuList.this, ActivityMenuDetail.class);
            iDetail.putExtra("menu_id", Menu_ID.get(position));
            startActivity(iDetail);
        }
```

and new activity will be open with product detail where i display add to cart button whenever i click on add to cart button item display in cart activity.

code is like

```
public void inputDialog() {

    // open database first
    try {
        dbhelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle(R.string.order);
    alert.setMessage(R.string.number_order);
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    final EditText edtQuantity = new EditText(this);
    int maxLength = 3;
    edtQuantity.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
    edtQuantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    alert.setView(edtQuantity);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String temp = edtQuantity.getText().toString();
            int quantity = 0;

            // when add button clicked add menu to order table in database
            if (!temp.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success add product to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (dbhelper.isDataExist(Menu_ID)) {
                    dbhelper.updateData(Menu_ID, quantity, (Menu_price * quantity));
                } else {
                    dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, quantity, (Menu_price * quantity));
                }
                checkoutButton.setEnabled(true);
                checkoutButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.ColorPrimaryDark);
                checkoutButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                dialog.cancel();
                checkoutButton.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            // when cancel button clicked close dialog
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

**Now the question is**

i want to display add to cart button in product list where i place my order directly from product list without opening product detail.

ListActivity is like

```
public class ActivityMenuList extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listMenu;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = null;
EditText edtKeyword;
ImageButton btnSearch;
TextView txtAlert;

// declare static variable to store tax and currency symbol
public static double Tax;
public static String Currency;

private ActivityMenuDetail details;

// declare adapter object to create custom menu list
AdapterMenuList mla;

// create arraylist variables to store data from server
public static ArrayList<Long> Menu_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
public static ArrayList<String> Menu_name = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<Double> Menu_price = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<String> Menu_image = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<Double> Discounted_Price = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static ArrayList<String> Discounted_Value = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<Double> Our_Price = new ArrayList<Double>();

String MenuAPI;
String fullAPI;
String TaxCurrencyAPI;
int IOConnect = 0;
long Category_ID;
String Category_name;
String Keyword;

// create price format
DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
DecimalFormat formatData1 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
DecimalFormat formatData2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_list);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_menu);
    }

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.orange, R.color.green, R.color.blue);

    prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    listMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
    edtKeyword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtKeyword);
    btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

    // menu API url
    MenuAPI = Config.ADMIN_PANEL_URL+"/api/get-menu-data-by-category-id2.php"+"?accesskey="+Config.AccessKey+"&category_id=";

    // tax and currency API url
    TaxCurrencyAPI = Config.ADMIN_PANEL_URL+"/api/get-tax-and-currency.php"+"?accesskey="+Config.AccessKey;

    // get category id and category name that sent from previous page
    Intent iGet = getIntent();
    Category_ID = iGet.getLongExtra("category_id",0);
    Category_name = iGet.getStringExtra("category_name");
    MenuAPI += Category_ID;

    mla = new AdapterMenuList(ActivityMenuList.this);

    // call asynctask class to request tax and currency data from server
    new getTaxCurrency().execute();

    // event listener to handle search button when clicked
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // get keyword and send it to server
            try {
                Keyword = URLEncoder.encode(edtKeyword.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            MenuAPI += "&keyword=" + Keyword;
            IOConnect = 0;
            listMenu.invalidateViews();
            clearData();
            new getDataTask().execute();
        }
    });

    // event listener to handle list when clicked
    listMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // go to menu detail page
            Intent iDetail = new Intent(ActivityMenuList.this, ActivityMenuDetail.class);
            iDetail.putExtra("menu_id", Menu_ID.get(position));
            startActivity(iDetail);
        }
    });

    // Using to refresh webpage when user swipes the screen
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    IOConnect = 0;
                    listMenu.invalidateViews();
                    clearData();
                    new getDataTask().execute();
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
    });

    listMenu.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            boolean enable = false;
            if (listMenu != null && listMenu.getChildCount() > 0) {
                boolean firstItemVisible = listMenu.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
                boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = listMenu.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
                enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
            }
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(enable);
        }
    });

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.cart:
        // refresh action
        Intent i = new Intent(ActivityMenuList.this, ActivityCart.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;

    case R.id.refresh:
        IOConnect = 0;
        listMenu.invalidateViews();
        clearData();
        new getDataTask().execute();
        return true;            

    case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        this.finish();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

// asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
public class getTaxCurrency extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    // show progressbar first
    getTaxCurrency(){
        if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
            prgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // parse json data from server in background
        parseJSONDataTax();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
        prgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // if internet connection and data available request menu data from server
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if((Currency != null) && IOConnect == 0){
            new getDataTask().execute();
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

// method to parse json data from server
public void parseJSONDataTax(){
    try {
        // request data from tax and currency API
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(TaxCurrencyAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }


        // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

        JSONObject object_tax = data.getJSONObject(0); 
        JSONObject tax = object_tax.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

        Tax = Double.parseDouble(tax.getString("Value"));

        JSONObject object_currency = data.getJSONObject(1); 
        JSONObject currency = object_currency.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

        Currency = currency.getString("Value");


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        IOConnect = 1;
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

// clear arraylist variables before used
void clearData(){
    Menu_ID.clear();
    Menu_name.clear();
    Menu_price.clear();
    Menu_image.clear();
    Discounted_Value.clear();
    Discounted_Price.clear();
    Our_Price.clear();
}

// asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    // show progressbar first
    getDataTask(){
        if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
            prgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // parse json data from server in background
        parseJSONData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
        prgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // if data available show data on list
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if(Menu_ID.size() > 0){
            listMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listMenu.setAdapter(mla);
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
}

// method to parse json data from server
public void parseJSONData(){

    clearData();

    try {
        // request data from menu API
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }

        // parse json data and store into arraylist variables
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

            JSONObject menu = object.getJSONObject("Menu");

            Menu_ID.add(Long.parseLong(menu.getString("Menu_ID")));
            Menu_name.add(menu.getString("Menu_name"));
            Menu_price.add(Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price"))));
            Discounted_Price.add(Double.valueOf(formatData1.format(menu.getDouble("Discounted_Price"))));
            Our_Price.add(Double.valueOf(formatData2.format(menu.getDouble("Our_Price"))));
            Menu_image.add(menu.getString("Menu_image"));
            Discounted_Value.add(menu.getString("Discounted_Value"));

        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //mla.imageLoader.clearCache();
    listMenu.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
{
    // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

ListAdapter code

```
public class AdapterMenuList extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
    private ActivityMenuDetail details;

public AdapterMenuList(Activity act) {
        this.activity = act;
    }

    public AdapterMenuList(ActivityMenuDetail details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return ActivityMenuList.Menu_ID.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lsv_item_menu_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
            holder.txtSubText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubText);
            holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageCatList);

            holder.discounted_Price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DiscPriceCatList);
            holder.discounted_Value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DiscValueCatList);
            holder.discounted_Price.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.discounted_Price.setPaintFlags(holder.discounted_Price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            holder.addtocart = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Listaddtocart);
            holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Listcardview);
            holder.our_Price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Our_Price);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.discounted_Value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    if(editable.toString().equals("0 % off") | editable.toString().equals("00 % off")){

                        // 1 - You can set empty text
                        holder.discounted_Value.setText("");
                        // 2 - Or you can change the color of the text
                        holder.discounted_Value.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        // 3 - Or you can change the visibility of the view
                        holder.discounted_Value.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }else{

                        //Here you should undo your code 

                        //1 - if you using method one dose not need to do anything here 
                        // for method 2 
                        holder.discounted_Value.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        // for method 3
                        holder.discounted_Value.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }


                }
            });

        holder.txtText.setText(ActivityMenuList.Menu_name.get(position));
        holder.txtSubText.setText("\u20B9" + ActivityMenuList.Menu_price.get(position));
        holder.discounted_Price.setText("\u20B9" + ActivityMenuList.Discounted_Price.get(position));
        holder.discounted_Value.setText(ActivityMenuList.Discounted_Value.get(position)+ " % off");
        holder.our_Price.setText("Our Price" + " " + "\u20B9" + ActivityMenuList.Our_Price.get(position));
        Picasso.with(activity).load(Config.ADMIN_PANEL_URL+"/"+ActivityMenuList.Menu_image.get(position)).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(holder.imgThumb);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtText, txtSubText, discounted_Price, quantity, discounted_Value, our_Price;
        ImageView imgThumb;
        TextView addtocart;
        LinearLayout layout;
    }

}
```

Any idea how can i put add to cart button in listview item where i place order from list without opening new activity.

thankx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is pretty straight forward to do.

Just add the "add to cart" option in every item itself.

So in the listview, show add to cart at the right most side where the user can click to add to the cart directly.

To get the click, in the base adapter in the getView() method, set the click listener on that holder item(add to cart button) and do the stuff in its onClick.

Comment: thankx for responding, i try this but i already tell that the add to cart button is in product details activity and i want to display the that button funcnality in listview activity.